# Read Dbx File From aWebsite(Iphone Development)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to read Dbx file In my App from The Following site.

http://www.weather.gov/geodata/catalog/wsom/data/bp03my11.dbx

How i can do This??Any suggestion or any Sample Source Code

Thanks in advance.

With best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search Iphone development Framework for your work.use nsdictionary to separate different identities